# Material UI: Hover colour doesn't change until values are changed and saved again

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code for an MUI TextField. When I run my code and hover over the bar, the color remains the default colour, which is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)`. Only when I change the value of something inside `sx` and save the file (recompiling the project) does it turn up blue on hover.

```
<TextField
shrink="false"
id="outlined-basic"
variant="standard"

sx = {{ 
    minWidth:"28%",
    minHeight:"50px",
    maxWidth:"28%",
    maxHeight:"50px",

    marginTop:"2vh",
    
    '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
      borderBottomColor: 'tomato',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before': {
      borderBottomColor: 'blue', 
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'green',
    },
}}>
</TextField>
```

For example, changing the value of `minWidth` and then recompiling will make it work properly, but changing the value of `variant` does not. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the strange behavior with recompiling, I don't have an answer. But, the problem can be fixed by applying the **sx** styles below for the **::before** pseudo-element. More classes are needed for specificity, and the order of `:hover` and `::before` matters.

```
'& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiInput-root.MuiInput-underline.MuiInputBase-formControl::before': {
    borderBottomColor: 'tomato'
},
'& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiInput-root.MuiInput-underline.MuiInputBase-formControl:hover::before': {
    borderBottomColor: 'blue'
},
```